# Dificuldade com IF e ELSE do Javascript - Retornar texto do resultado na tela

Tags: javascript, if, else

**DÚVIDA:** Como faço um IF ELSE com javascript para que exiba um texto (Ex: Aprovado) quando localizar uma determinada palavra (Ex: Verde). Meu código atual é esse abaixo, mas não está funcionando e não consigo encontrar o problema. Sou iniciante com Javascript, então caso alguém souber me ajudar agradeço!

```
var status_atual = 'Azul'; //

   if (status_atual = "Verde") {
  return 'Aprovado';
} else if (status_atual = "Vermelho") {
  return 'Reprovado';
} else if (status_atual = "Amarelo") {
  return 'Incompleto';
} else if (status_atual = "Azul") {
  return 'Novo';
} else {
  return 'Cor e status não identificados!';
}
```

Eu precisava fazer com que o resultado fosse exibido na tabela, igual como é feito no PHP com a função echo, dessa forma por exemplo:

```
<?php

$status_atual = 'Azul';

   if ($status_atual = 'Verde') {
  echo 'Aprovado';
} else if ($status_atual = 'Vermelho') {
  echo 'Reprovado';
} else if ($status_atual = 'Amarelo') {
  echo 'Incompleto';
} else if ($status_atual = 'Azul') {
  echo 'Novo';
} else {
  echo 'Cor e status não identificados!';
}

?>
```

Exemplo do resultado IF ELSE sendo exibido na tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Note que tanto o código JS quanto o PHP apresentam problemas.

Comment: Operador de comparação é `==` ou `===`.  O `=` sozinho é operador de atribuição.

Answer (score 1):

Em muitas linguagens de programação, assim como no javascript, o operador `=` não é um comparador, mas atribui o valor a uma variável.

Nesse seu caso, substirua-o, onde estiver fazendo comparações, por `==`.

No Javascript há também o operador `===`. Procure ler sobre a diferença entre os 2.

Segue fiddle de exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/jhtcsLw7/.

Comment: Certo, obrigado pela resposta. Preciso colocar esse if else dentro desse outro código heheheh, teria alguma ideia de como seria feito isso?

`{
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return 'CODIGOIFELSEAQUI';

                },
                "targets": 3
            },`

Comment: Tentei fazer dessa forma, consegue dar uma olhada? https://jsfiddle.net/h9e1mkcn/

Comment: @BrunoFariasProgramming criei um fiddle como exemplo. Note que no fiddle que vc enviou vc trocou o `=` na `atribuição` também.

Comment: Concordo com o @tvdias. Sei que na pergunta menciona claramente que quer usar um `if/else`. Porém, nestes casos penso que seria mais adequado utilizar um `switch/case`. Fica a sugestão.